# Mostrar datos en un TextArea mediante una consulta en SQL

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos

estoy tratando de hacer que una consulta en una base de datos para que se muestre en un textArea en vez de una tabla, sin embargo no logo hacerlo y no se en donde pudiera estar el error espero puedan ayudarme.

```
public void MostrarPersonaltxtArea(JTextArea txtReport) {
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
    int num = 0;
    try {
        st = conexion.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from Empleado");
        while (rs.next()) {
            num++;
            Object[] registro = {num,rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getInt(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8)};
            ta.append(registro);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error no se puede ejecutar la consulta " + e);
    }
```

Comment: Recuerda evitar repetir preguntas en sitio, cual es el error que se presenta?

Comment: me sale que no puedo convertir en objeto en string en este caso el objeto es registro

Comment: Ok marco, entiendo ahora lo que comentas, agregué una respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de realizarlo de acuerdo a tu código, por ejemplo puedes convertir a String los elementos del Array y agregarlos a tu `JTextArea` :

```
  ...
  ...
  Object[] registro = {num,rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getInt(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8)};
  ta.append(Arrays.toString(registro));
  ...
  ...
```

También puedes iterar el array  `Object[]` y agregar los elementos:

```
  ...
  ...
  Object[] registro = {num,rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getInt(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8)};
  for(int i = 0; i < registro.length; i++){
       ta.append(registro[i]);
   }
  ...
  ...
```